# Adding a QGLWidget to a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opengl, qglwidget

I have a MainWindow class with a QGraphicsView which I'd like to add to a MainWindow, so that I'm able to see what's actually going on. All I'm trying to do right now is render a cube.

**Main Function**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow Ctor**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent )
    : QMainWindow( parent ),
      mUi( new Ui::MainWindow ),
      mDisplay( new GLWidget ),
      mScene( new QGraphicsScene )
{
    mUi->setupUi( this );
    //mScene->addWidget( mDisplay );
    QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView;
    //QGraphicsView::setupViewport( this );
    graphicsView->setViewport( mDisplay );
    graphicsView->show();
}
```

**GLWidget::initializeGL**

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL( void )
{
    glMatrixMode( GL_COLOR );

    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

    glClearDepth( 1.0f );

    glEnable( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnable( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable( GL_MULTISAMPLE );
    static GLfloat lightPosition[ 4 ] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition );

    qDebug() << "GL Initialized" << '\n';
}
```

As you can see, `glClearColor` is supposed to set the background to a black screen. The problem is that when I render it, I see two windows which pop up and not one. While the `MainWindow` class has a window frame which is supposed to render the `GLWidget`, it appears that, rather than adding it to the window frame, it simply generates both of the frame as well as the window using the `QGraphicsView`. Both windows only show a white screen; one of them is at least supposed to show a black background, as the `glClearColor` states.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

glClearColor only sets the color that will be used to clear the screen.
To actually clear the screen you must call glCear function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Same thing with glClearDepth - it only sets value of depth to clear with. To actually clear it use the same glCler function. You can clear color buffer and depth buffer with one glClear call like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Hmm...it looks like you were wrong: there is no such as thing as `GL_COLOR_BUFFER`, at least, according to Qt's Specification (along with the fact that I'm doing this from Windows 7 - Linux may be different). Now, there is `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, but, that's about it AFIK.

Comment: No, you call glClearColor, then glClear, otherwise OpenGL won't know what colour to use when clearing.  And it is `*_BIT`, it is not a Qt or Linux thing, the names are specified in the OpenGL specification.

Comment: @Holland: yes, you're right. I forgot _BIT suffix. And what do you mean - Qt specification? Use OpenGL manual, or man pages: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml

Comment: Ok, thank you. The Qt specification for OpenGL operates a little differently than the normal OpenGL specs. Buffer binding is entirely different, for example.